# To solve polynomial equation of a special form.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

It is known that there is no general method to solve polynomial with order greater than 5. However, some equations of the special forms have been knowns to solve.
While I was studying today, I faced the following problems.

$Ax^{n}+Bx^{m}=C$

where $n > m >0$, $A$, $B$ and $C$ are constants.

My attempt is here.
Let $y = x^m$ then $x^n$ can be rewritten as $y^p$ for some $p>0$. so the problem is converted into

$Ay^p+By =C $

I do not know what to do anymore.
I tried to do the change of variables but failed.
Does this equation have a solution? If so, who can offer me some helpful advice? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Since $p$ will not be an integer in general, this is leaving the realm of polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no general approach. You can look for rational roots and try to factor the polynomial; or sometimes, if you get very lucky, you can find a clever substitution that turns the polynomial into one where all powers of the unknown have a common divisor, so that you reduce the degree of the polynomial (this is the essence of the trick behind Cardano's formula for solving cubics).

But even for something as simple as $-x^5 + x =1$, there is no solution in terms of radicals.